# Reusing grep output

Tags: shell-script, variable

I'm writing a script to print the pending TODOs in a project, but I'm having troubles reusing one of the variables. To make things more clear here is the code I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
todos="$(grep "TODO:" ./src -R)"
number_of_todos="$(echo "$todos" | wc -l)"

if [[ $number_of_todos -gt 0 ]];
then
    echo "List of TODOS:"
    echo $todos
else
    echo "There are no pending TODOs."
fi
```

In this case, the script always goes through the `then` part of the `if` clause, no matter the value of `number_of_todos`. But, if I define `number_of_todos` as

```
number_of_todos="$(echo "$todos" | wc -l)"
```

then the code works correctly. I want to reuse the `grep` output so as not to repeat code. What am I missing?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean "in this case"? You seem to have the same code twice. Was it supposed to be something else?

Comment: I meant "in the previous code". I want to reuse the value of the `todos` variable, but it seems I'm not doing it right as the `if` condition is always true, even when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify: `grep` exits not-zero on not finding anything (or you could check whether `TODOS` contains anything within the shell via a `-n "$TODOS"` test).

```
#!/bin/sh
TODOS=$(grep -R 'TODO:' ./src)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo not ok
    echo $TODOS
else
    echo ok
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
todos=( "$(grep TODO: ./src -R)" )

if [[ ${#todos[@]} -gt 0 ]];
then
    echo "List of TODOS:"
    echo "${todos[@]}"
else
    echo "There are no pending TODOs."
fi
```